# File not found exception while retrieving file from Google Drive with Google Drive Picker (.Net)

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api, google-picker

File not found exception while retrieving file from Google Drive with Google Drive Picker (.Net)

I ran in problems while placing the Google Drive Picker on my page.

The picker self is working fine, I got a fileid back from the picker, but when I try to download the selected file from Google Drive on the server, based on the given fileId, I get a 'File not found' message from Google.

**What I've done so far:**

- Created a new google account;
- Created new project;
- On the 'APIs & auth' section under 'APIs', enabled Google Picker API, Drive API and Drive SDK;
- Configured Drive SDK  On the 'APIs & auth' section under 'Credentials', adding credentials /accounts;
- On the 'APIs & auth' section under 'Consent screen', configure project details (Emailaddress, ProductName);
- Added the Google Client Api for .Net dll's to my project (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v2/)

The following accounts are created under 'Credentials'section:

- Client ID for web application (Here I configured the redirect URIS
  and Javascript ORigins. I used this client id in the Javascript on
  the client side;
- Service Account, used on the server side (I downloaded the P12 certificate as generated by Google and used this Emailaddress in the code behind);

My client side code (based on the Google Drive Api samples)

```
var developerKey = '<api_key>';
var clientId = '<client_id>';
var appId = '<app_id>';
var scope = <scopes (drive.readonly and drive.file>;
var apiLoaded = false;

var pickerApiLoaded = false;
var oauthToken;

// Use the API Loader script to load google.picker and gapi.auth.
function onApiLoad() {
    apiLoaded = true;
}

function onPickerClick() {
    gapi.load('auth', { 'callback': onAuthApiLoad });
    gapi.load('picker', { 'callback': onPickerApiLoad });
}

function onAuthApiLoad() {
    window.gapi.auth.authorize(
        {
            'client_id': clientId,
            'scope': scope,
            'immediate': false
        },
        handleAuthResult);
}

function onPickerApiLoad() {
    pickerApiLoaded = true;
    createPicker();
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
        createPicker();
    }
}

function createPicker() {
    if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
            setAppId(appId).
            addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCUMENTS).
            setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
            setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
            setCallback(pickerCallback).
            build();

        picker.setVisible(true);
    }
}

function pickerCallback(data) {
    if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];

        var fileName = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenFieldFileName.ClientID%>');
        fileName.value = doc.name;

        var fileId = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenFieldFileId.ClientID%>');
        fileId.value = doc.id;
    }
}
```

Code-behind:

```
   public IExternalFile GetFile()
    {
        var fileId = HiddenFieldFileId.Value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileId))
        {
            try
            {
                var accountEmail = "<email setting from service account>";
                var certificatePath = "<path to the service account certificate>";
                var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

                var serviceAccount =
                    new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(accountEmail)
                        {
                            Scopes = new[] {DriveService.Scope.DriveFile, DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly}
                        }.FromCertificate(certificate));

                // Create the service.
                var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = serviceAccount,
                        ApplicationName = "<application name, configured in the Google Project"
                    });

                var file = service.Files.Get(fileId).Execute();
                var content = service.HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(file.DownloadUrl).Result;
                var size = (content != null) ? content.Length : 0;
                return new ExternalFile(file.OriginalFilename, size, content);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // error handling
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

The errormessage:

Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError

```
File not found: <fileId> [404]
Errors [
Message[File not found: <fileId>] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global]
]
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
File not found: <fileId> [404]
Errors [
Message[File not found: <fileId>] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global]
]
```